# Арифметические операции над Char в Си

Tags: c

Если в элементах массива типа char лежат два элемента, считанных с клавиатуры(точно цифры) и требуется записать в элемент третьего массива тоже типа char их сумму, как это реализовать?

Comment: `char c = a - '0' + b - '0' + '0';` -> `char c = a+b-'0';` хотя может и просто `char c = a+b;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[3]{'5', '8'};
    a[2] = a[0] - '0' + a[1] - '0';
    printf("%d\n", int(a[2]));
}
```